# Matriz com colunas dinamicas?

Tags: c

Tenho uma matriz assim:
`int numeros[qNum][6];`

Na realidade ela armazena um numero inteiro por linha, separando os algarismos, exemplo:

Tenho o numero 1234, na matriz ficara:
`numeros[0][0] = 1;`
`numeros[0][1] = 2;`

E assim por diante.
Porem tenho números compostos por 4, 5 e 6 algarismos, como faço para definir a matriz com colunas dinâmicas, pois desse jeito a linha 0 nao ta ficando 1234 e sim 123400. Ou seja, ela está tendo sempre 6 colunas, preenchendo o numero que eu quero e completando o restante das colunas com 0. Como faço para isso não acontecer, exemplo ter uma matriz com as linhas:

1234
14086
815108
Sem os zeros para atrapalhar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mete zeros à esquerda

```
// 1234
numeros[0][0] = 0; numeros[0][1] = 0; numeros[0][2] = 1;
      numeros[0][3] = 2; numeros[0][4] = 3; numeros[0][5] = 4;

// 14086
numeros[1][0] = 0; numeros[1][1] = 1; numeros[1][2] = 4;
      numeros[1][3] = 0; numeros[1][4] = 8; numeros[1][5] = 6;

// 815108
numeros[2][0] = 8; numeros[2][1] = 1; numeros[2][2] = 5;
      numeros[2][3] = 1; numeros[2][4] = 0; numeros[2][5] = 8;
```

Comment: Nesse caso 0 a esquerda também vale alguma coisa. Porque na realidade é um jogo de caça números (trabalho da faculdade) daí estou colocando esses números em uma matriz para depois aloca-los aleatoriamente em outra matriz para gerar o tabuleiro do game

Comment: Ha como eu ler um vetor de inteiro e armazenar cada algarismo digitado em uma posição dele?

Comment: Podes experimentar com um valor diferente para significar posição vazia, por exemplo, `-1`: `numeros[0][0] = 1; numeros[0][1] = 2; numeros[0][2] = 3; numeros[0][3] = 4; numeros[0][4] = -1; numeros[0][5] = -1;`